# S3 presigned URL fails when deployed to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, asp.net-core, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I'm trying to use a presigned URL to upload files to S3. It works fine in my testing enviroment, but when I try and use the same code in the live environment (on elastic beanstalk) it returns an "AccessDenied" error.

I notice that the live request has completely different parameters, though the code is the same.
On localhost I have:

> X-Amz-Expires, X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, X-Amz-Date, X-Amz-SignedHeaders, X-Amz-Signature

On live I have:

> AWSAccessKeyId, Expires,x-amz-security-token, Signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined the issue. I hadn't authenticated the live servers, but had done so on our own machines.

Comment: Hi Dave, could you tell what you did? Once I added a more appropriate credentials to account my upload error code changed from 401 to 400, I have same problem. Need something I can explain to admin

Comment: I had authenticated the development servers using the CLI - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html